# How to avoid insertion of duplicate data using SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert a profile record for office clearances. the insertion of office name is done using trigger.

My problem is that whenever I insert new profile record the previous inserted office id and profile id is inserted in the newly inserted record. See the image below:
[image]

Below is the snippets of the trigger code along with other images for references:

[image]

[image]

Any Idea or code snippet is a great help...

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your trigger's insert query you have selected these two values using select subquery.